# Mean value of second differential

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

I have shown the first part that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is that, in the second part they tell find the mean value of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ , how do I do this ? I don't understand what they mean or how to do this.

Comment: the mean value of a function over an interval is the definite integral of the function over that interval, divided by the length of the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value of a function is definite integral of the function over that interval divided by the length of the interval.

In this case :

$$\int_a^b \frac{(t-1)e^{-t}}{4(2-t)^3}$$

Where  a and b you can find using the given range :

$$0\leq x \leq \frac{7}{4}$$